# StructureMap: How to get base message handler for derived message? (command handler pattern)

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have the following message hierarchy and want StructureMap to return me the corresponding message handler as shown below (note: one handler is for all messages derived from YMessageBase):

```
abstract class XMessageBase { ... }
class AMessage : XMessageBase { ... }

abstract class YMessageBase { ... }
class BMessage: YMessageBase { ... }

AMessageHandler : AbstractMessageHandler<AMessage> { ...  }
YMessageBaseHandler : AbstractMessageHandler<YMessageBase> { ... }
```

I setup StructureMap like so:

```
        Scan(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
            cfg.IncludeNamespace("Namespace.With.Above.Types");
            cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(AbstractMessageHandler<>));
            cfg.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
```

And I'm trying to handle messages like this:

```
ProcessMessage(object message) 
{
    var messageType = message.GetType();
    var handlerType = typeof(AbstractMessageHandler<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);
    var handler = (IMessageHandler)ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance(handlerType);
    handler.Handle(message);
}
```

**The problem is**, in the case of `BMessage`, this approach is asking StructureMap for `AbstractMessageHandler<BMessage>` when really it needs to locate `AbstractMessageHandler<YMessageBase>` ... the result is that it does not find a handler.

Can anyone give some advice on how to use StructureMap to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to traverse up the `messageType` hierarchy, making calls to `container.TryGetInstance` until you get a handler.

FYI - if you didn't have to look up the type hierarchy, StructureMap has syntax to support the pattern of finding a handler for an object based on its type:

```
handler = ObjectFactory.Container.ForObject(message).
  GetClosedTypeOf(typeof(AbstractMessageHandler<>)).
  As<IMessageHandler>();
```